# Getting wrong result after comparing data

Tags: java

I write the following code that will read a line, convert them into integer and count how many even, odd, and zero digits in a line.

But the problem is that, whenever I enter zero, it will make calculation on the countEven in my code, rather than countZero.

What's wrong with my code?
I don't have any problem on count even digits and odd digits in my code, it's just zeros.

```
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = "";
    int countOdd = 0, countEven = 0, countZero = 0;

    str = stdin.nextLine();
    char[] breakDown = str.toCharArray();

    Integer convertInt;


    for (int i = 0; i < breakDown.length; i++)  {
        convertInt = new Integer(breakDown[i]);

        if (convertInt % 2 == 1)
            countOdd++;  

        if (convertInt % 2 == 0 && convertInt != 0)
            countEven++;

        if (convertInt == 0)
            countZero++;  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast the character `'0'` to an integer, it becomes 48, not 0.  The expression `breakDown[i]` is of type `char`, but it is getting cast to `int` when you pass it to the `Integer` constructor.

You could just get rid of the conversion to `Integer` and write this inside your loop.

```
    if (breakDown[i] % 2 == 1) {
        countOdd++;  
    }

    if (breakDown[i] % 2 == 0 && breakDown[i] != '0') {
        countEven++;
    }

    if (breakDown[i] == '0') {
        countZero++;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a better solution than mine, this works because the ASCII codes of the digits 0-9 are between 0x30 and 0x39. So for example 1 is 0x31 and thats odd.

Comment: Ah I see!!! Thank you and thanks lwi ^_^   In other words, it converts the "0" character into the ASCII code, rather than directly convert it into int type, right?  One more question:  the char type (breakdown[i]) can be directly divided by numbers, as long as those characters are numbers, right?

Comment: If you try to do arithmetic with a `char`, it will be treated like a number.  It doesn't have to be in the range from `'0'` to `'9'`.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem you have in your code is that `new Integer(breakDown[i])` returns the value of the ASCII code and not the actual value of the digit. So it return 0x30, this is even and your code correctly increases `countEven` and not countZero.

First solution in my mind, use `Integer.valueOf(breakDown[i]-0x30)` instead.